# what ?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight is doing and how?

Tags: java, android

- public static final int listPreferredItemHeight

Ok, of course I understand this part of the expression...listPreferredItemHeight is the preferred list item height.

But I really don't get these stuff. Anyone can point me to the right direction where I can read about that?

> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

the example where I find this code is here https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

EDIT: in the example at the link the code is `android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"`. What exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The marker "?" means that you are referring to a style attribute. So `?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight` simply means **"use the value defined by the attribute called listPreferredItemHeight in the namespace android."**

This attribute and its value are part of the Android framework, hence the "android" namespace.

Comment: how can i find listPreferredItemHeigh value?

Comment: This will return the value:

TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
  getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight, typedValue, true);
  DisplayMetrics metrics = new android.util.DisplayMetrics();
  getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
  return (int) typedValue.getDimension(metrics);

Comment: For anyone else arriving here and wondering where the documentation for this is, I found this rather helpful:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes

Answer (score 8):

`android:layout_height=`**`"?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"`**

**`?[<package_name>:][<resource_type>/]<resource_name>`** taken from [Referencing Styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes).

The `?` is used for referencing style attributes, where as the more familiar looking`@` is used for normal resources.

Style attribute resources reference values in the currently applied theme. So values may differ between different themes.

The value of `listPrefferedItemHeight`, found in the android package of the currently applied theme is returned to `android:layout_height`.
The resource type `attr` in the line of code above is optional and can be omitted. Therefore, the following is also correct:

**`?android:listPreferredItemHeight`**